# Preg_match allow all domains

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using a php check_email function with preg_match to allow people to make an account on a webshop. Everything is ok, but it doesn't accept domains like @myname.bike of @myname.gent. What do I have to change to accept all domains?

This is the function that I have now:

```
!preg_match("/^(?:[\w\d-]+\.?)+@(?:(?:[\w\d]\-?)+\.)+\w{2,4}$/", $email)
```

I already tried changing a few things behind the @, but it's not working.
What is wrong?

Comment: FYI: `\w` includes `\d` so `[\w\d]` can be simplified with `\w`. 2 up to 4 characters is a little bit short for TLD, see: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db . Please, have a look at these sites: valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: php has already a filter to validate emails: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want your regex to match emails with no name and a domain only? Like `@example.com`? If this is the case you just need to change that very first `+` (one or more characters) to a `?`  (zero or more characters)

## Before

`!preg_match("/^(?:[\w\d-]+\.?)+@(?:(?:[\w\d]\-?)+\.)+\w{2,4}$/", $email)`

## After

`!preg_match("/^(?:[\w\d-]?\.?)+@(?:(?:[\w\d]\-?)+\.)+\w{2,4}$/", $email)`

Comment: No that's not the case. Normally you have email addresses like name@gmail.com or name@business.net or so. But I have clients that have not have a .com, .net or any regular domain extension, but they have like .bike, .amsterdam, .ghent,... And the preg_match doesn't accept them.

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is not with preg_match but with your regex. The part at the end that says ````\w{2,4}```` says domains can only be a 2-4 characters in length. So anything longer than 4 characters (.amesterdam for example) will not be matched. You can change it to ````\w{2,}```` which means **minimum of 2, no maximum** or you can change it to ````\w{2,10}```` for **minimum of 2, maximum of 10** for example. Make sense? You can always [test your regexp online here](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: I tried that, with 2,10 for the e-mail test@cec.bike for example, but it's not working. Going to check that link. Thanks

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like? the line `!preg_match('...',$email)` Means **return false on match** so if this line of code is supposed to return true on a valid email, the preceding `!` before preg_match will return false on a valid email.